# Database design for hang out website

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'd like to create a DB (MySQL) for a hang out website but I can't see an optimum design for it (Is my very first DB). The main problem is that the club change the entrance price or the music style in function of the day of the week, so I don't now how to solve this. 
Btw, do you know any good handbook for DB design with MySQL?

Thank you so much!
Regards.

Comment: You will need to post more specifically the type of data you intend to store, what you have tried, and what *specific* problems you are running into before you are likely to get help on SO.

Comment: Type of data is for the club: name, address, website, number... I have just made one table with these attributes and I thought about adding a 'day of the week' in that table so I could specify prices, styles and other changing attributes in that table too. But this means to use x7 more elements in the table 'clubs'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely read about databases, foreign keys etc.. These are basics and you won't get anywhere without that knowledge.

But to get you started, here is a simple structure that should do the job for what you requested. Hopefully I understood that correctly, because you really gave very little detail here.

Tables:

1) CLUB - 
has attributes, that are static - don't change very often like ID, name, address, website, phone number etc.

Example of data row:

```
ID  name    website        phone
1   clubA   www.aclub.com  565-554-666
2   clubB   www.bclub.com  523-552-778
```

2) MUSIC - table of music styles, attributes: ID, style_name)

Example of data row:

```
ID    style_name
1      jazz
2      metal
3      techno
```

3) CLUB_DETAIL - connects tables club and music by foreign keys, sometimes called cross table, holds information, which belongs to both tables, attributes: ID, club_id, music_id, date, price

Example of data row:

```
ID    club_ID   music_ID   day_of_week   entrance_fee
1       1          1          Monday         10$
2       1          2          Tuesday         8$
3       2          3          Monday          6$
.. etc.
```

ID is primary key in each table and uniquely identifies the record, club_ID is a foreign key to ID in table CLUB.

In table CLUB_DETAIL you can have all the possible combinations you need, so you do not need to have columns duplicated 7x in CLUB table.

This is just an example, real world use-case would be probably different, but you gave not enough information to be more specific.
Instead of day_of_week I would use date, which would give me more flexibility should the schedules change of rotate on different than week basis.

Comment: This is what I was looking for more or less. Thank you so much and sorry for the poor information. Can you recommend me any handbook to get initiated in databases knowledge? Thank you sir.

Comment: Not really, I have not read any book on that matter, I learned from experts and internet. There is a lot of tutorials for DB basics on internet. Just google it, you will find more than you would be able or willing to read.
If this helped you, please vote me up, I need some reputation to interact more freely here.